# Sum in loop not displaying actual result?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, variables, initialization

I am suppossed to sum the squares of the all the natural numbers until it reaches some input, but the result becomes larger than it should. As I set 3 as input, the outcome becomes 3*10⁹ or so, could you please tell if I am missing a mistake with data types or operations?

BTW, when does using functions become more efficient than writing whatever in the main code? I have quite a few doubts on when I should or should not use them.

Thanks to whomever might read it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input, sum;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
        sum += i*i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sum`, after the `int input, sum;` line? Since you never assign it until `sum += i*i;`, which reads the value of `sum` before adding on to it.

Comment: in other words, initialize `sum` first

Comment: it should be 0, is the sum declaration the only mistake?

Comment: Seems to be, yes.

Comment: @Ruungak "_it should be 0_" No. Why would you think so? The actual value is indeterminate.

Comment: is there any better way to declare, or would just adding a new "sum = 0" line be the best practice?

Comment: I would go for sum = 0 instead of sum = o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize `sum`, so there is no guarantee that the value starts at 0. In fact, it's initial value is essentially undefined. You should simply add the line `sum = 0;` before your for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input, sum;
    sum = 0;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
        sum += i*i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

"BTW, when does using functions become more efficient than writing whatever in the main code"

It isn't necessarily more efficient, but for larger projects it is easier to read code when common functionality has been grouped into reusable functions. As a general rule of thumb, if you are writing the same code/algorithm more than once, you should write a function for that code/algorithm.

**NOTE** - As pointed out by others there happens to be a formula for calculating the sum of squares without a loop.

`sum = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6`

This is what is known as an *order of 1*, or `O(1)`, solution because a single atomic operation can be performed to achieve the results you are looking for. On the other hand, the loop solution is considered *order of n*, or `O(n)`, since `n` iterations of the loop must be performed to achieve the results of the routine. The `O(1)` solution is considered optimal. If you use large values as your input then you will see why. However, if you are new to programming then your teachers will not expect you to know much about algorithm analysis and the original solution above should be fine.

Comment: So is there a need to write functions if I can make it all inside a loop?

Comment: Functions have their usefulness when writing code. In this example, a function isn't necessarily useful. If the code within `main` became very long, or if  you repeated the same code when it could be abstracted into a reusable function, then it would be a great idea to use functions for organization, clarity, and code-reuse.

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize the variable `sum` with `0` and then the program will be run successfully. When you use `sum` without initializing it, the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Also you can use below formula instead of the for loop:

`sum = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the closed form solution. This is by far the best answer in my opinion. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to resolve your problem.

The first one is to place the declaration of the variable sum before main. For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum;

int main(){
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
        sum += i*i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

In this case the variable will have the static storage duration and will be initislized by the compiler with 0.

Otherwise the variable have the automatic storage duration and must be initialized explicitly like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input, sum = 0;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
        sum += i*i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Pay attention to that it is better to declare the variable as having the type long long int because the sum of squares can be too big and will not fit into an object of the type int. For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int input;
    long long int sum =0;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++){
        sum += ( long long int )i*i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice thorough analysis (as usual) but why do you neglect to mention the closed form solution?

Comment: @Bathsheba What do you mean?

Comment: Using the bss trick to initialize sum to 0 is clever, but it seems a bit lazy in this case and if this is a new programmer it only serves to confuse them, or even lose points from their professor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: `sum = input * (input + 1) * (2 * input + 1) / 6`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Indeed, but it's your *duty* to point out an O(1) way if there exists one. Remember that answers are not necessarily targeted at the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize `sum`. So whenever you do `sum += i * i`, you are adding numbers to a trash value.
This is the reason you get incorrect results.
To fix this, simply replace `int input, sum;` with `int input, sum(0);`.